# FFmpeg run multiple filters in parallel from C API

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editor, streaming, decoding

I successfully applied a FFmpeg filter from C API (my previous question [here](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/27554/call-ffmpeg-filter-from-source-code-c-api)). I see the filters are running sequentially. Now the question is, how can I run multiple filters in parallel? If run sequentially, that causes so much delays.

I'm using ffmpeg as the base for stream processing. As we receive the streams, I need to apply 2 filters and produce metadata in parallel. Of course, with minimum delay issues.

Answer (score 1):

Filters cant really run in parallel because they can modify frames, and you can’t modify a frame in two threads at the same time. You can make a copy of the frame and run two filter graphs.

Comment: Yes. Of course. But the filters I am targeting should only read frames (for detection. Like freezedetect, silencedetect, and blackdetect).

Comment: Btw, when calling a filter, it gets a `buffersrc` along with the frame. Each filter should have its own buffer, right?

Comment: Yes, you can use separate filtergraph for each detection filter you use, i dunno how much speed gain you can expect from this. It is same approach as running 2 or more ffmpeg commands in parallel.